# Display an imageView in the default UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I create a new `UITableView`, I can setup
cell.imageView. Isn't that, in theory, supposed to show an image?
Is the only way to actually show an image inside a `UITableViewCell` to create a custom cell subclass?

This is the code I'm using:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell (style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = practices[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = practices[indexPath.row].address?.displayString()

//this doesn't show an image   
        cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        cell.imageView?.image = practices[indexPath.row].logo

        return (cell)
    }
```

Comment: This should indeed show an image. Are you sure that `practices[indexPath.row].logo` is not `nil`?

Comment: @chief - for the time being use cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: “an-image”) and add a test image "an-image" in app bundle to see if that works first. If that worked then issue is with practices[indexPath.row].logo

Answer (score 3):

You should be dequeueing a cell rather than allocating a new one each time:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell
    cell.imageView?.image = practices[indexPath.row].logo
    return cell
}
```

As suggested by others, add a test image to your xcassets to verify that the problem isn't with the logo in the practices array.

Answer (score 1):

> is the only way to actually show an image in a cell is to create a
>   costume cell ?

No that is not true. you can set it as follows also that you did :

```
cell.imageView?.image = some UIImage
```

In your code

```
cell.imageView?.image = practices[indexPath.row].logo
```

please check `practices[indexPath.row].logo` actually have an `UIImage`

Also a side-note, use `dequeueReusableCell`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "someCellName", for: indexPath)
```

instead of allocating it every time in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: @chief - for the time being use cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: “an-image”) and add a test image "an-image" in app bundle to see if that works first. If that worked then issue is with practices[indexPath.row].logo

Answer (score 0):

please check:

```
if practices[indexPath.row].logo is UIImage {
    print("My logo is not UIImage")
    cell.imageView?.image = nil
} else {
    print("My logo is UIImage")
    cell.imageView?.image = practices[indexPath.row].logo
}
```